# Como acessar Virtual Host de outro pc na mesma rede

Tags: php, aplicação-web, phpmyadmin, apache

Quero acessar meu site local que está no #PC1 pelo celular ou pelo #PC2, porém eu só consigo acessa-lo pelo próprio computador em q ele está, e se tento entrar de outro computador só funciona se eu colocar o IP da minha maquina ao invés do Virtual Host em q o site está.
 Exemplo: Crei um virtual Host no apache com o nome de SITE1.LOCALHOST só que quando coloco esse dominio em outro pc pra poder ver o site, ele não carrega, a não ser que eu coloque o IP do servidor, que acaba levando ao LOCALHOST

Comment: VirtualHost é configurado para apontar quando acessado, o arquivo `hosts` é para acesso local, para acessar o servidor teria que configurar no roteador, ou então criar um proxy, o que dependeria de configurar o computador principal como servidor proxy e os demais teria que configurar a interface de rede (ou via sistema operacional). Ou então configurar o `c:/windows/system32/drivers/hosts` (ou `/etc/hosts` em Linux) do PC2 para apontar para o IP do PC1, por exemplo `192.168.0.101   site1.localhost`

Comment: Essa de mudar o arquivo host de cada computador eu já sabia, porém quero que quando qualquer dispositivo conecte na rede, possa acessar o site local, se puder me explicar melhor essa de configurar no roteador ajudaria muito